# Exclude file extensions in top level directory, but not in subdirectory with WinRAR command line

Tags: command-line, winrar

I'm trying to rar some files with the WinRAR command line. The files have this structure:

```
Top-Level Dir
|    Text1.txt
|    Text2.txt
|    XML1.xml
|    XML2.xml
|    Inner Dir
|    |    Inner1.txt
|    |    Inner2.txt
|    |    InnerXML1.xml
|    |    InnerXML2.xml
```

It's also possible for the Top-level Dir and the Inner Dir to have more subdirectories.

I can successfully rar the files and preserve the structure that I want, but I'm trying to exclude .xml files only from the top-level directory. I want my archive to look like this:

```
Top-Level Dir
|    Text1.txt
|    Text2.txt
|    Inner Dir
|    |    Inner1.txt
|    |    Inner2.txt
|    |    InnerXML1.xml
|    |    InnerXML2.xml
```

I can only manage to remove .xml files from sub-directories of `Top-level Dir`. Anything else I try removes all of them. I've tried a number of combinations of the following commands:

```
rar a -ep1 -x*.xml <destination> <source>
rar a -ep1 -x..\*.xml <destination> <source>
rar a -ep1 -r- -x*.xml <destination> <source>
rar a -ep1 -x*\..\*.xml <destination> <source>
```

I'm hoping that I just don't understand how specify the path correctly.

Help is appreciated.

Edit: I'm running a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd <source>
$ mkdir ../tmpdir
$ mv *.xml -t ../tmpdir
$ rar a <destination> <source>
$ mv ../tmpdir/* ./
$ rmdir ../tmpdir
```

Comment: That is only a workaround.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. I should also have mentioned that I was on a Windows box (I will update the question). I did convert these commands to Windows and it does do the trick as a batch file, but it's a few more steps than I wanted. I'm still looking for something native to WinRAR. This does work though.